# Quickly calculate the number of shared neighbor between any pair of nodes from an adjacency matrix

Tags: r, matrix, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I'm wondering if there's a way to quickly calculate the number of shared neighbors between any pairs of nodes (i.e., the number of nodes connected to both node i and j) from an adjacency matrix (like the one below) and then return the output in matrix format?

I've referenced these following posts,
[Find common neighbors of selected vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60816290/find-common-neighbors-of-selected-vertices)
[Counting the number of neighbors in common between two vertices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739787/counting-the-number-of-neighbors-in-common-between-two-vertices-in-r)
[Calculate number of common neighbors in igraph R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952559/calculate-number-of-common-neighbors-in-igraph-r)

but can't seem to find many clues to do what I want to achieve. I was told that this can be directly calculated as `adjm'`*`adjm`, but I am not sure if this makes sense. It will be really appreciated if someone could shed some light on this.

```
# create an adj. matrix
adjm <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.6,0.4)), nc=10)

# set diagonal element to 0
diag(adjm) <- 0

# making it symmetric 
adjm[lower.tri(adjm)] = t(adjm)[lower.tri(adjm)]
```

Comment: Is your graph directed or undirected?

Comment: @Szabolcs  Dear Sir, undirected

Comment: In that case, transposition is unnecessary, as the adjacency matrix is symmetric.

Comment: @Szabolcs I seem to get the same result when applying this method to symmetric cases. A'A gives me the exact same result as that computed by AA.

Comment: Yes, of course, since A = A'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  you can get the number of shared neighbors by computing the *matrix*
product of adjm' and adjm.  Since you are using R, `adjm'*adjm` means
the component-wise product of the matrices.  We want the matrix product,
so you need to use %*%.  I will use that below.

To simplify the notation,  I will denote adjm = A where
A[i,j] is 1 if there is a link between nodes i and j (they are neighbors)
and A[i,j] = 0 otherwise.

Let's compute t(A) %*% A.

The i-jth coordinate of t(A) %*% A is

```
(t(A) %*% A)[i,j] = 
sum(t(A)[i,k] * A[k,j])  =
sum(A[k,i] * A[k,j])
```

All of the products in the sum are either 0 or 1.
If both A[k,i]=1 and A[k,j]=1,  the product is 1,
otherwise it is zero. So `(t(A)%*%A)[i,j]`  is equal to the
number of different k's for which both A[k,i]=1 and
A[k,j]=1.  But A[k,i]=1 means k is a neighbor of i
and A[k,j]=1 means k is a neighbor of j, so
`(t(A)%*%A)[i,j]`  is equal to the number of different k's
for which k is a neighbor of both i and j.

Let's try it out on your example.  In order to make the results
reproducible,  I set the random.seed.

```
library(igraph)

## For reproducibility
set.seed(1492)

# create an adj. matrix
adjm <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.6,0.4)), nc=10)

# set diagonal element to 0
diag(adjm) <- 0

# making it symmetric 
adjm[lower.tri(adjm)] = t(adjm)[lower.tri(adjm)]

Shared = t(adjm) %*% adjm

g = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjm, mode = "undirected")
plot(g)
```

[image: Example graph]

Notice for example that Shared[1,4] = 4.
That is because nodes 1 and 4 have four shared neighbors,
Nodes 2,3,6 and 9. Shared[5,7]=0  because nodes 5 and 7
have no neighbors in common.

Answer (score 2):

If the graph is undirected, then the matrix of the number of shared neighbours is `A.A`, where I used `.` to denote the matrix product. As others note, the correct operator in R is `%*%`.  *Transposition is not necessary*, since in the undirected case, the adjacency matrix is symmetric: `A' = A`.

If the graph is directed, let's assume that `A_{ij}` denotes the number of connections *from `i` to `j`* (this is igraph's interpretation).

Then the `i,j` element of `A'.A` gives the number of nodes that point to both `i` and `j` (`i <- v -> j`), and `A.A'` gives the number of nodes that both `i` and `j` point to (`i -> v <- j`). These quantities are sometimes called *cocitation* and *bibliographic coupling*, respectively, and can be computed [using `cocitation()` and `bibcoupling()` in igraph](https://igraph.org/r/html/latest/cocitation.html). In the undirected case, both of these functions return the same, thus you may use either.

Comment: Thanks again for point this out. The `cocitation()` function is indeed recommended in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739787/counting-the-number-of-neighbors-in-common-between-two-vertices-in-r.

Answer (score 1):

I think [@G5W's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69957946/12158757) is super concise already, highly recommended!

Below is a graph theory way to solve it, maybe not that efficient:

```
> nb <- neighborhood(g,mindist = 1)

> outer(nb, nb, FUN = Vectorize(function(a, b) length(intersect(a, b))))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    6    1    1    4    2    2    2    5    3     1
 [2,]    1    3    2    0    1    3    0    1    2     1
 [3,]    1    2    4    1    2    4    1    1    3     3
 [4,]    4    0    1    4    2    1    1    3    2     1
 [5,]    2    1    2    2    4    2    0    1    3     2
 [6,]    2    3    4    1    2    5    1    2    3     3
 [7,]    2    0    1    1    0    1    2    2    1     1
 [8,]    5    1    1    3    1    2    2    5    3     1
 [9,]    3    2    3    2    3    3    1    3    7     3
[10,]    1    1    3    1    2    3    1    1    3     4

> t(adjm) %*% adjm
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    6    1    1    4    2    2    2    5    3     1
 [2,]    1    3    2    0    1    3    0    1    2     1
 [3,]    1    2    4    1    2    4    1    1    3     3
 [4,]    4    0    1    4    2    1    1    3    2     1
 [5,]    2    1    2    2    4    2    0    1    3     2
 [6,]    2    3    4    1    2    5    1    2    3     3
 [7,]    2    0    1    1    0    1    2    2    1     1
 [8,]    5    1    1    3    1    2    2    5    3     1
 [9,]    3    2    3    2    3    3    1    3    7     3
[10,]    1    1    3    1    2    3    1    1    3     4
```